# How to load $cookies in Angular service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

I've defined an angular service in which I'd like to access some a cookie. Looking at the AngularJS docs it seems that [$cookieStore is deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookieStore) 
and that `$cookies` should be favored. Here is how my service looks:

```
'use strict';

var lunchrServices = angular.module('lunchrServices', ['ngCookies']);

lunchrServices.service('authService', ['$cookies', function ($cookies) {
    var user = $cookies.get('user') || null;

    this.login = function (userEmail) {
        user = userEmail;
        $cookies.put('user', userEmail)
    };
    this.logout = function () {
        user = null;
        $cookies.put('user', null);
    };
    this.currentUser = function(){
        return user;
    }

}]);
```

which errors out the on the `$cookies.get('user')` call with `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. However, if I change every instance of `$cookies` to `$cookieStore` it works perfectly (shown below):

'use strict';

```
var lunchrServices = angular.module('lunchrServices', ['ngCookies']);

lunchrServices.service('authService', ['$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    var user = $cookieStore.get('user') || null;

    this.login = function (userEmail) {
        user = userEmail;
        $cookieStore.put('user', userEmail)
    };
    this.logout = function () {
        user = null;
        $cookieStore.put('user', null);
    };
    this.currentUser = function(){
        return user;
    }

}]);
```

I'd like to use `$cookies` but can't figure out why it fails when `$cookieStore` doesn't. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume it has something to do with this line in the docs

> BREAKING CHANGE: $cookies no longer exposes properties that represent
>   the current browser cookie values. Now you must use the
>   get/put/remove/etc. methods as described below.

Which might mean that the previous version of angular didnt have those methods on $cookies.

Your version might be that older version.

Comment: Welp, that's embarrassing. You're just all over my questions tonight...

Thanks! :)